# Bootstrap 4 server-side validation and input group append

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've got a form that has an input with an appended icon using the `input-append` class. I'm doing server side validation on the form.

If an error message is returned, then I add the message to a `div` with the class `invalid-feedback` within the same parent as the `input` (which has the class `is-invalid`). The CSS selector controlling the error messages visibility is `.form-control.is-invalid ~ .invalid-feedback`.

My issue comes with the `input-append` which has the following CSS selector `.input-group > .input-group-append:not(:last-child) > .input-group-text`. This determines whether or not the appended `div` is the last one and rounds the it's corners if it is.

However, `<div class="invalid-feedback">` becomes the `:last-child` so the `input-group-append` doesn't get rounded corners. The snippet below shows this.

Is this a known Bootstrap issue, or have I done something wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>Bootstrap 4</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row p-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="sr-only">End Date/Time</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">Start Date</div>
        </div>

        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" placeholder="Date Input">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text"><i class="oi oi-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Error Message
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more digging, it seems that this is a known issue. See [issue #25110](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25110) on GitHub. I didn't find it in the first place because I wasn't searching for the right thing.

User **cbossi** [suggets a fix](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25110#issuecomment-371630552) using the `order` classes. See the snippet below for an example. Essentially, to make the error message `div` not the `:last-child` of the `input-group`, you put it before the appended group. Then you use the `order-1` class to reorder the content.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>Bootstrap 4</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row p-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="sr-only">End Date/Time</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">Start Date</div>
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback order-1">
          Error Message
        </div>

        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" placeholder="Date Input">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text"><i class="oi oi-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

There are currently some [known issues](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23454) with the Bootstrap 4 input-group and validation classes.

A workaround I have found is to keep in the `invalid-feeback` the 2nd to last element inside the `input-group`, so that the `input-group-append` remains the last child. This allows the `input-group-append` to have proper rounded corners. Then use the `order-last` utility class on `invalid-feedback` so that is displays last.

https://www.codeply.com/go/DMDBmq8TJg

```
<div class="row p-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only">End Date/Time</label>
        <div class="input-group ">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">Start Date</div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" placeholder="Date Input">
            <div class="invalid-feedback order-last ">
                Error Message
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="oi oi-calendar"></i> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We just posted at exactly the same time! I found the open issue eventually, so have found a similar fix. Thanks.